# Commit this new files to a repository

Tags: linux, subversion

How do I commit a file?

https://piazza-resources.s3.amazonaws.com/j6zdjr2o14g248/j7hl17d3fku6te/lab1.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIEDNRLJ4AZKBW6HA&Expires=1505530921&Signature=PXnvBnz2m%2B%2FIwMpc1q2T6pmU7Ow%3D

Not asking the entire thing just this part (I've done all the prior):

4. Commit this new file to your repository  (Step 3 part 4)

svn commit keeps giving me error of this isn't a working copy?

Comment: You problably have to `svn add thefile` first. If this works like git (I'm not an svn expert). But: you seriously should have listened to your teacher! Also: for coding you might be better off at stackoverflow.com, but I'm not sure if it is distinguished.

Comment: My teacher kinda like expects us to know this without it being taught... we only had 1 lecture most of it being first class introduction. We were given like a free book to read on SVN but its pretty massive and not compulsory. I learn better by practicing and this is a challenge because im so extremely new to this software, ill try out stackoverflow

Comment: SVN has really fallen out of fashion. Only used in very legacy projects these days. Do they ever update their course material?